# Why do we need to call context.delete to delete an item from NSManagedObject array?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Suppose I have;

```
var itemArray = [Item]()
```

and Item is a NSManagedObject. Item has two attributes "Title":String and "Done":Boolean. Here is the picture of my data model.

[image]

```
//  Item+CoreDataClass.swift

//  This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.
//

 import Foundation
 import CoreData

 public class Item: NSManagedObject {

 }
```

When I change the value of Done and call context.save, it is automatically reflected to Persistent Container. However, when I remove an element from array by saying,

```
itemArray.remove(at: someindex)
```

and call context.save. The item is not deleted from Persistent Container. Only if I called,

```
context.delete(itemArray[someindex])
```

then the item is truly deleted from store.

So why only removing from itemArray and save context is not sufficient although changing an attribute' value and save context is sufficient for successful CRUD operation on Core Data?

Comment: Why would Core Data know about your variables and properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change an attribute on an Item object then Core Data (actually the NSManagedObjectContext) detects that since the Item belongs to the NSManagedObjectContext and the item is marked as dirty. But your array has no connection to the NSManagedObjectContext in any way so any changes you make it to remains undetected by the NSManagedObjectContext and that is why you need to tell it explicitly that you want to delete the item you removed from the array.

Another way to look at it is that anything you create/define in your Core Data model is known by NSManagedObjectContext but anything created outside in swift code is unknown. If you start working with to-many relationships between entities you will see that then adding or removing objects from the to-many collection will be handled directly by the NSManagedObjectContext in a way you expected for your array.

Answer (score 1):

The array `var itemArray = [Item]()` has no direct relation with the underlying database. Therefore removing items from that array doesn't affect the Core Data database.

To create, save or delete NSManagedObject instances in a Core Data database you need to call the related functions of a valid NSManagedObjectContext.

Answer (score 1):

Any operation on CoreData should be done through `NSManagedObjectContext` as it is the scratchpad to access or update any entity in database. So in your case while deleting the `Item` entity, you should do that through context only to get reflected on database.

```
var itemArray = [Item]()
let context = //get your context
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Item")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: " (primaryKey == %@) ", "your_primary_key")
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
itemArray = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
for i in 0 ..< itemArray.count where i < itemArray.count-1 {
    context.delete(itemArray[i])
}

do {
    try context.save()
} catch {
    // print the error
}
```

Comment: I am wondering about why update call directly reflected on CoreData base.